# Refresh token endpoint not working correctly - AADSTS90033

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Since the recent outage, getting refresh tokens seems to be broken, even though the status account says everything is back to normal. Any idea what could be causing this?

```
"response": {
    "statusCode": 503,
    "body": {
        "error": "temporarily_unavailable",
        "error_description": "AADSTS90033: A transient error has occurred. Please try again.\r\nTrace ID: 988f6bab-9fde-44c7-b480-a2dd07fd4900\r\nCorrelation ID: 031c9c04-389f-4b45-9b45-a1f4ee1b5d75\r\nTimestamp: 2020-09-28 22:41:10Z",
        "error_codes": [90033],
        "timestamp": "2020-09-28 22:41:10Z",
        "trace_id": "988f6bab-9fde-44c7-b480-a2dd07fd4900",
        "correlation_id": "031c9c04-389f-4b45-9b45-a1f4ee1b5d75"
    },
    "headers": {
        "cache-control": "no-store, no-cache",
        "pragma": "no-cache",
        "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        "expires": "-1",
        "strict-transport-security": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains",
        "x-content-type-options": "nosniff",
        "p3p": "CP=\"DSP CUR OTPi IND OTRi ONL FIN\"",
        "x-ms-request-id": "988f6bab-9fde-44c7-b480-a2dd07fd4900",
        "x-ms-ests-server": "2.1.11063.14 - WEULR2 ProdSlices",
        "set-cookie": ["fpc=...; expires=Wed, 28-Oct-2020 22:41:10 GMT; path=/; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=None", "x-ms-gateway-slice=estsfd; path=/; secure; httponly", "stsservicecookie=estsfd; path=/; secure; httponly"],
        "date": "Mon, 28 Sep 2020 22:41:10 GMT",
        "connection": "close",
        "content-length": "424"
    },
    "request": {
        "uri": {
            "protocol": "https:",
            "slashes": true,
            "auth": null,
            "host": "login.microsoftonline.com",
            "port": 443,
            "hostname": "login.microsoftonline.com",
            "hash": null,
            "search": null,
            "query": null,
            "pathname": "/common/oauth2/v2.0/token",
            "path": "/common/oauth2/v2.0/token",
            "href": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token"
        },
        "method": "POST",
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "accept": "application/json",
            "content-length": 1607
        }
    }
```

Getting access tokens seems to work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was part of the recent outage, please try again now. It has been resolved.